# Retrieving and Convert Oracle long data type in to java String with special characters

Tags: java, oracle

I'm trying to get long data type from an oracle database table and it is as follows.

[image]

But rs.getLong("cloumn") not supported and with rs.getString("cloumn") this retrieved as follows.

"\"\u003c!DOCTYPE html\u003e\n\u003chtml\u003e\n\u003chead\u003e\n\u003c/head\u003e\n\u003cbody\u003e\n\u003cp\u003efsdfs drgrgr gesegter\u003c/p\u003e\n\u003c/body\u003e\n\u003c/html\u003e\"

I want to retrieve the long data with special characters as mentioned earlier.

Please suggest me a method to get the correct value.

Database admin doesn't allow to change the data type. Therefore value should be correctly retrieve from long data type.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That column does not contain long(s). Your question is very unclear; in what way is an html document a long?

Comment: I updated the question with database sample. Please refer those. What I want to do is getting this html tag as a string and save in a variable

Comment: `long` is a deprecated type, if you have opportunity, convert it to `CLOB` or `BLOB` type.

Comment: Database admin doesn't allow for change data type. Are there any way to retrieve the value?

Comment: Have you tried `CAST` somthing like  `SELECT CAST(TERMS AS char) FROM "YOUR_TABLE"`

Comment: casting doesn't work as this error will given. java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got LONG

Comment: Your database appears to be corrupt. Talk to the DBA. Ask if there's some kind of mapping going on. Because otherwise, it's time to restore the database (because a column of LONG(s) should not contain TEXT).